# setting image to imageview dynamically in listview item doesn't work properly

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, scroll, imageview

I have a **listview** where each list item has some imageview and some textview. I'm using intent to open **gallery**, pick an selected image and assign it to imageview but my problem is that when the image is set to that imageview as soon as I scroll my listview, the selected image **disappears** and the original image appears on that place.
So can any one tell me why is it so and how can i avoid it ?

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(
                                    Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent,
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case SELECT_PHOTO:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            /*
             * InputStream imageStream=null; try { imageStream =
             * getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage); } catch
             * (FileNotFoundException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch
             * block e.printStackTrace(); } Bitmap image =
             * BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
             */
            try {
                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) lv.getChildAt(position);
                ImageView im = (ImageView) ll
                        .findViewById(R.id.image);
                Bitmap b = decodeUri(selectedImage); 
                Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(b.getWidth(),
                        b.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(b, TileMode.CLAMP,
                        TileMode.CLAMP);
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setShader(shader);
                Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
                c.drawCircle(b.getWidth() / 2, b.getHeight() / 2,
                        b.getWidth() / 2, paint);
                im.setImageBitmap(circleBitmap);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }                                   SELECT_PHOTO);


private Bitmap decodeUri(Uri selectedImage) throws FileNotFoundException {
// Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o);

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 40;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
                break;
            }
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o2);

    }
```

Comment: Can u post your code u have done so far .. ??

Comment: @ Selvin very funny , if you don't wanna help better don't comment.

Comment: @Shubham yes, it was very funny and if you don't wanna get funny comments better do not post unclear questions ...

Answer (score 0):

You should update your listadapter, or the source of your listadapter. The adapter is the model for your data. Your view will automatically update when you call notifyDatasetChanged on the adapter afer you updated it with the new value.

Comment: The selected image replaces the original image, but on scrolling it changes again . I'm not adding anything after that so how notifyDataSetChanged can help?

Comment: As I said, The adapter is the model for your data, the items in the list are a view on a record in the adapter.
So you update the model and not the views, your views will automatically update when you update your model and call notifyDatasetChanged();

One rule of thumb: Never update the views in a listview manually, only in ListView.getView(). ListView.getView() is called after the dataset was invalidated in the adapter

Comment: actually i have set that image view for user to click and then stick his own picture to that image view so i can't do it in Listview.getView() method.

Comment: Yes you can, and you should. can you show the code for the adapter?